# Flutter iOS app working perfect in simulator but not in real device

Tags: ios, flutter

My application working perfect in simulator but not working in real iOS device. Application crashes at startup.

i am using this lib in my project.

```
http: ^0.12.0+2
      connectivity: ^0.4.2
      fluttertoast: ^3.1.0
      shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
      google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
      flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
      dots_indicator: ^1.2.0
      percent_indicator: ^2.1.6
      cached_network_image: ^2.3.2+1
      razorpay_flutter: 1.2.3
      image_picker: ^0.6.0+17
      flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.5.1+4
      webview_flutter: 1.0.7
      device_info: ^1.0.0
      store_launcher: ^1.0.1
      package_info: ^0.4.3+2
      flutter_tex: ^3.6.7+9
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your project with Xcode to know why it crash.
Real device need you configure signing with your Apple ID.